# set Icon on Polygon corners in google map api 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a polygon which is editable so when i start to edit it it shows small icon on it.
Below in picture an arrow icon (for undo changes).

[image]

so i want to add another icon by my own so user can delete that polygon by clicking on it. So ho to add icon there?

**Update**
Here is what i do so far
[`Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/Lerwytuk/7/)
Now i just want to add icon when polygon complete event fired.

Comment: @duncan i update a question. I have only problem that how to add some icon when polygon complete

Answer (score 1):

So you've already got the event listener for when the polygon is complete.

What you could do is add a marker in the middle of your polygon, with a custom icon that looks similar or identical to the 'undo' icon Google are using.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.FALSE);

    // find out the paths of this polygon
    var path = polygon.getPath();

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(path.getAt(i));
    }

    var centre = bounds.getCenter();

    // add a marker here:
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: centre,
        map: map,
        icon: 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
    });
});
```